# How to copy paste, receiving error for VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a cell from a worksheet represented by "a" into the current sheet through this code. In the current sheet, I chose a reference point and then go to the last column, and then do an offset into a new column to paste.

This line is EXACTLY like another code I have in my larger code, not sure why its not working and giving a Run Time error

Anybody have thoughts?

Code that works:

```
Range("b15").End(xlToRight).Copy Range("B15").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
```

Code that does not work:

```
a.Range("D24").Copy Range("A4").End(x1ToRight).Offset(0, 1)
```

Run time or user defined error

Comment: You are using `x1` one not `xl`  L....!

Comment: I voted to close this question because: *"Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error."* are off-topic.

Comment: Note that if there is no value right of A4 then `.End(xlToRight)` will move to the very right cell in Excel and `Offset(0, 1)` will try to go one more right wich exceeds the amount of columns and fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `x1` **One**, It should be **L**

**Try this:**

```
a.Range("D24").Copy Range("A4").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
```

Also, I would suggest you to use a Sheet reference for Destination in above line.

Comment: WOW, I legit thought it was 1 not L. THX so much for the help sir!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used **1** instead of **l** in the second snippet of code.  Change it to the letter,

```
a.Range("D24").Copy Range("A4").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
```